# SyntaxError: invalid non-printable character U+0016. What is the cause?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import secrets
from secrets import TOKEN

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot is ready.")

client.run(f"{TOKEN}")
```

I'm using VSC and I just wrote this code into my main file. I'm not sure why but it keeps saying:

```
File "<stdin>", line 1
    ▬▬▬& C:/Users/username/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python311/python.exe c:/Users/username/OneDrive/Desktop/PythonCode/main.py
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid non-printable character U+0016
```

Anyone know what would be the cause of it?

Comment: are you trying to run the file inside a python shell?

Comment: You're trying to run a command meant for the system shell in a Python shell/REPL. Or if the IDE generated that command, it's running it in the wrong shell for some reason.

Comment: To be very clear, the problem isn't with your code itself; the problem with is how you have VSC configured to try to run your code. You haven't shown us that configuration, so I don't know that this is answerable with only the information included in the question.

Comment: Unicode Character "" (U+0016)

Answer (score 0):

Your Python file seems perfectly fine from a syntax point of view. This WebRepl has no problem parsing it: https://www.online-python.com/LE9maKwF8z . (It can't find discord, but that's fine and the syntax is ok).

It looks like a VSC problem. Try saving the file and run it with

```
python3 main.py
```

to validate that's it is a VSC problem.

Edit:
Maybe one of the quotes is off, but isn't in the StackOverflow paste.

Comment: This should be a comment; a proper _answer_ would describe how to fix VSC's configuration.

Comment: Still isn't working. Saving the file and running it from the outside and still get the error message;
```py
>>> python3 main.py
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    python3 main.py
            ^^^^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: The file you pasted here is valid, but many editors to magic with ". So please delete all your quotes and retype them manually.

Comment: I think retyping the quotes fixed it...

Comment: If your file had bad quotes, we could have told you about that if you'd copied-and-pasted the code direct from the editor where it didn't work (so it would also have bad quotes in the question here) instead of retyping it.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the part about re-typing @CharlesDuffy . The retyping was done in VSC; the Code above is copy&pasted. Additionally some editors do fancy things with quotes, even when doing copy&paste.